# Unable to migrate projects to organization with no organization

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, migrate, organization

I want to manage the security in GCP but it said to add an organization and migrate all my projects to the said organization.

I looked through their documentation and basically I have to either create a workspace account or a Cloud Identity management account. Since we don't need workspace I decided to opt for the latter.

I have created an account, filled out the details like adding my organization name, domain and my dns as well. Now what? Where and how do I add organization? I thought this might it but when I checked I still can't migrate and it says to add organization. I get this: `You do not belong to any organizations. You must belong to an organization to migrate a project. Learn more`

I don't know what step I am missing here.

Comment: The organization was automatically created for you. Provide details on what you created and configured. Note: the organization is a child resource of your Cloud Identity resource. Check in the Google Cloud web GUI to see how you set things up. Make sure you are authenticated with the correct credentials.

Comment: This link should help you: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization

Comment: @JohnHanley I did use that link to create cloud identity account. That is what I meant when I said I looked at the documentation. The next part is where I am stuck. All I did was create the cloud identity account. Provide it with name, phone number, email address and domain. Now I have logged in to admin.google.com. Where should I go to create the organization? Is that all I needed to do? Because even after that I don't see any organization.

Answer (score 1):

Find out if you do have created the Organization with the command

`gcloud organizations list`

Create a new project from that Organization, even if you have no need to use that new project.

Lastly you would need to:

1. Give the email account/user the `Project Mover` (*access to update and move projects) role on the Project to be moved.
2. Give the email account/user the `Project Creator` role on the destination Organization
3. On the Destination Organization, you will need the `roles/orgpolicy.policyAdmin` (Organization Policy Admin) role or you can just give the email account the Organization Admin role for both Organizations
4. Check below constraints (this is in IAM & Admin > Organization Policies):

   a. Destination Org > Allow `constraints/resourcemanager.allowedImportSources`
5. Then issue this command in Cloud Shell once all the above requirements are met: 
   `gcloud beta projects move [Project-ID] --organization [ORG-ID]`
   OR 
   `gcloud beta projects move PROJECT_ID \ --organization ORGANIZATION_ID`

You may also check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration) for reference

Comment: There's no organization when I run `gcloud organizations list`

Comment: @DarkDead Did you figure this out? I have the same problem. Created a new org and tried to migrate everything over to that (instead of using "no organization") but now all my projects are missing during the migration. When I run the `gcloud organizations list` command I also get no organizations.

Comment: I did not. It's such hassle and a headache. I gave up. :(